# Keycloak Docker container (jboss) ran with a compose is not running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jboss, keycloak

Hi everyone I'm trying to do a demo repo to use keycloak but I don't know why it's not running correctly.

Here is my docker compose

```
version: "3.8"
volumes:
  data:
services:
  db:
    container_name: db-dev
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: dev
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: devPassword
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U dev -d postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 10s
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend-dev
    image: frontend-dev
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      target: development
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/frontend/src
      - ./frontend/public:/frontend/public
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
  backend:
    container_name: backend-dev
    image: backend-dev
    build:
      context: ./backend
      target: development
    depends_on:
      - media
      - db
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "--silent"]
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
  auth:
    container_name: auth-dev
    image: jboss/keycloak
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment: 
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=ChangeMe
      - DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES
      - DB_ADDR=db-dev
      - DB_DATABASE=postgres
      - DB_SCHEMA=public
      - DB_USER=dev
      - DB_PASSWORD=devPassword
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING="true"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://localhost:8080 || exit 1
      interval: 30s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
      timeout: 10s
```

but http://localhost:8080/auth/ gives me ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

frontend is up and running, backend and db (i can access with dbeaver) too and I've already had them communicate with each other.

Any idea of what's wrong?

I tried to remove the healthcheck of the auth container with this result:

```
auth-dev       | Added 'admin' to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json', restart server to load user
auth-dev       | -b 0.0.0.0
auth-dev       | =========================================================================
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       |   Using PostgreSQL database
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | =========================================================================
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:06:50,036 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (CLI command executor) JBoss Modules version 2.0.0.Final
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:06:50,406 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (CLI command executor) JBoss MSC version 1.4.13.Final
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:06:50,441 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (CLI command executor) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:06:50,967 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 16.1.1 (WildFly Core 18.0.4.Final) starting
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:06:51,311 INFO  [org.jboss.vfs] (MSC service thread 1-6) VFS000002: Failed to clean existing content for temp file provider of type temp. Enable DEBUG level log to find what caused this
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
auth-dev       | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.wildfly.extension.elytron.SSLDefinitions (jar:file:/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/org/wildfly/extension/elytron/main/wildfly-elytron-integration-18.0.4.Final.jar!/) to method com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider.isFIPS()
auth-dev       | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.wildfly.extension.elytron.SSLDefinitions
auth-dev       | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
auth-dev       | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:06:54,181 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.18.3.Final
auth-dev       |
```

I expected to see the keycloak admin page but http://localhost:8080/auth/ gives me  the same ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I even tried to use another approach and launch only db+keycloak with this [Medium page that i tried](https://gruchalski.com/posts/2020-09-03-keycloak-with-docker-compose/) but i have the same error in logs:

```
auth-dev       | Added 'admin' to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json', restart server to load user
auth-dev       | -b 0.0.0.0
auth-dev       | =========================================================================
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       |   Using PostgreSQL database
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | =========================================================================
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:00:12,328 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (CLI command executor) JBoss Modules version 2.0.0.Final
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:00:12,714 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (CLI command executor) JBoss MSC version 1.4.13.Final
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:00:12,749 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (CLI command executor) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:00:13,212 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 16.1.1 (WildFly Core 18.0.4.Final) starting
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:00:13,673 INFO  [org.jboss.vfs] (MSC service thread 1-6) VFS000002: Failed to clean existing content for temp file provider of type temp. Enable DEBUG level log to find what caused this
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
auth-dev       | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.wildfly.extension.elytron.SSLDefinitions (jar:file:/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/org/wildfly/extension/elytron/main/wildfly-elytron-integration-18.0.4.Final.jar!/) to method com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider.isFIPS()
auth-dev       | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.wildfly.extension.elytron.SSLDefinitions
auth-dev       | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
auth-dev       | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:00:16,638 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.18.3.Final
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:00:21,765 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYELY00023: KeyStore file '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore' does not exist. Used blank.
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:00:21,804 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYELY01084: KeyStore /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self-signed certificate for host localhost
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:00:21,991 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYPAT0050: Keycloak cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:00:22,636 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:00:22,654 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Keycloak 16.1.1 (WildFly Core 18.0.4.Final) started in 10233ms - Started 49 of 72 services (24 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | The batch executed successfully
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 
auth-dev       | 16:00:23,603 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 16.1.1 (WildFly Core 18.0.4.Final) stopped in 96ms
auth-dev       |
```

I expected to see keycloak console on http://localhost:28080/auth/ as in the medium, but no luck.

Comment: apparently jboss instance is not working correctly, to whom might need this, use
[quay.io](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker) one.

This can be closed.

Comment: Apparently, you might need to debug to see what is going on. Maybe, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598456/keycloak-crash-during-startup-when-using-mysql) solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @UmutTEKİN , i just solved using another docker image.